# After upgrading to macOS Ventura, MacBook began to run out of battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, charging, ventura

When I put the MacBook into sleep mode on Monterey for the night, and pulled it out of the power socket, the charge was consumed by about 5% per night.

Now about 60-80% is consumed on macOS Ventura without an outlet turned on overnight, and in the morning my MacBook is almost completely discharged.

Can I fix it somehow, or should I just wait for Apple to fix it?

I have MacBook Pro 16-inch 2019.

Screenshot of my battery this night:

[image: iStat Menus showing graph of battery consistently declining from 100% to 43%.]

Comment: That's not normal behaviour. The most likely scenario is that some old third-party process is 'going beserk' on the new OS, and using up all the battery. Use Activity Monitor to see what's going on. If you must use Chrome (which is well known for using masses of RAM and CPU, to say nothing of security issues), then make sure you're up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed itself in later updates.